Why cannot we take base and (or) argument of a $\log$ function as negative?
Consider $\log_{b} a = y$ as the standard logarithmic equation.
Here, why cannot we take negative values of $b$ and (or) $a$?
For example, the following example would perfectly fit in:
$$\log_{-3}(-27) = 3 \iff -27 = (-3)^3$$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Does this help?

Under certain conditions we can. For instance, in $p$-adics logarithms make the most sense when the base is $\equiv1\bmod p$ ($\bmod 4$ for $p=2$), regardless of sign. But not in real analysis.
